# MongoDB errors: mongodb-10gen E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: linux, mongodb

I'm trying to install things in Linux (Crunchbang Linux - a derivation of Debian), and I'm getting errors which point towards mongodb-20gen.

When I try to remove it using :-

```
cometbill@Linuxn00b:~$ sudo apt-get remove mongodb-10gen
```

I get ...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mongodb-10gen
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 221 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 81657 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-10gen ...
arg: remove
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-10gen
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I read something on here for similar errors with MongoDB, and it suggested removing mongo-clients, so, I tried:-

```
cometbill@Linuxn00b:~$ sudo apt-get remove mongodb-clients
```

and get:-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mongodb-clients' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mongodb-10gen (2.4.6) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-10gen
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This is probably something more for ask ubuntu or server fault, I know your not running ubunut but try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195950/package-system-broken-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1

Comment: @Sammaye add your comment as an answer. I tried it and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to some corruption within the package manager dpkg itself, this thread from Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/195950/package-system-broken-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1 lists some solutions, more specifically the editing of the status file has been noted as one that always works.

Answer (score 8):

This is a difficult state to get out of. You should be able to complete the removal if you create a fake init script:

```
sudo touch /etc/init.d/mongodb
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/mongodb
```

Answer (score 2):

For mongodb v3.4

```
sudo touch /etc/init.d/mongod
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/mongod
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force installation of package:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.6.5_amd64.deb
```

Then resume with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride`

Then remove first 2 line entries and try again

```
**mongodb mongodb 755 /var/log/mongodb
mongodb mongodb 755 /var/lib/mongodb**
root crontab 2755 /usr/bin/crontab
root mlocate 2755 /usr/bin/mlocate
root ssl-cert 710 /etc/ssl/private
root messagebus 4754 /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, this process will be break at line.

```
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
```

You must be create fake file,

```
sudo touch /etc/init.d/mongodb
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/mongodb
```

and process will complete.