# MongoDB can not be installed in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04, parse-server

```
zguindouos@zguindouos:~$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
[sudo] password for zguindouos: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-org is already the newest version (3.2.12).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic (4.4.0-66.87) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-66-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-66-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.66.70); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic:
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems preventNo apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                     No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                         No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
     No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                          configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 4.4.0.66.70); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-66-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-66-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[MongoDB errors: mongodb-10gen E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727408/mongodb-errors-mongodb-10gen-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-cod)

Comment: It looks like your disk is full:
``gzip: stdout: No space left on device``

Comment: Looks like MongoDB is already successfully installed: `mongodb-org is already the newest version (3.2.12).`

Comment: It's work Thanks :)